# Pizza order - extra cheese

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

I'm having problems understanding JavaScript. I have the following assignment. I'm trying to add to the final cost. the Extra Cheese.

```
var extraCheeseUpcharge = 1.5
var extraCheese = confirm("Would you like extra cheese?")

if (extraCheese == true) {
  pizza.extraCheese =  true;
  extraCheese = extraCheeseUpcharge + pizza.cost;
} else {
   pizza.extraCheese =  false;
  extraCheese = extraCheeseUpcharge - pizza.cost;
  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] to better understand how to get the most from the site.  Your post doesn't include a clear question statement.  You have said you are having problems, but not specified what the problem is.  Ideally, if possible, you include a clear question, a [mcve], steps to reproduce, the expected output, and the actual output.  All these elements may not always be required, but a clear question statement generally is.  I'd recommend updating with a clear question.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: why would you subtract the cost of the pizza from the upcharge if there is no extra cheese. wouldn't you just add the upcharge to the pizza cost only if extra cheese is asked for?

Comment: Thank you so much, next time I would post a clear question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var extraCheeseUpcharge = 1.5
var extraCheese = confirm("Would you like extra cheese?")

if (extraCheese == true) {
  pizza.extraCheese =  true;
  extraCheese = extraCheeseUpcharge + pizza.cost;
} else {
   pizza.extraCheese =  false;
  extraCheese = pizza.cost;
}
```

If extraCheese is false, the final price here would be equal to pizza.cost and not extraCheeseUpcharge - pizza.cost

Comment: Thank you so much!! You are correct. I spend so many hours and I couldn't see that detail. (when the extraCheese is false).

Comment: @KarenM - glad this answer helped you!  Please remember to mark it as your selected answer (by clicking the checkbox to the upper left of the answer) and vote it up if you have sufficient reputation points.  Good luck, and happy coding!